# d3 time format for YYYY-MM-DD ie. 2013-02-04

Tags: javascript, d3.js, date-format

I am getting

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

from my console at this line

`var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;`

`data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.Day = parseDate(d.Day);
});`

here is how my date is formatted in my json object `day: "2013-02-04"`

Comment: Can you try using an alternative approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse ?  I usually use something like `Date(Date.parse("2005-07-08"));`.

Comment: Sounds like the error message is coming from somewhere else. Can you post a complete minimal example?

Comment: Is the lowercase 'day' in the object a mistake? Or is it supposed to be 'Day' as in the reference?

Comment: yeah, this was correct @cmonkey it was supposed to be lowercase day. I have another problem now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the case of 'day' is incorrect.
I can execute:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
parseDate( "2013-02-03" )
```

Without issue (it shows the correct Date). Likely, you need to change the code to:

```
data.forEach(function(d) { d.day = parseDate(d.day); });
```

(note, lowercase 'd' in 'day')